# US visa application after refusal (change in circumstances)

Tags: visas, visa-refusals, b1-b2-visas, us-visa

I applied for a US tourist visa in September 2017 to visit my family from Germany that was refused citing the reason under section 214(b): Ties to home country are not strong. I asked the VO about the definition of the home country in my case and he told me it's Germany (where the application was submitted). I was on a student visa at that time.

I would like to apply for the visa again. I am an Indian citizen working as a researcher at the moment and hold an EU Blue card. I have been living in Germany for more than 3 years. I have a good travel history and visited many countries in past for tourism. In the US embassy website, they maintain that I shouldn't apply for the visa again until my circumstances change significantly.

I would like to know if having a full-time job for some time qualifies as the change in circumstances?

Shall I wait for some more time (until I get the Permanent Residence in Germany) and does the time-period between the applications play any role?

I know it might primarily be an opinion based question but still, I would appreciate if I get some comments.

Comment: Which other countries have you visited? Are you single or married or have children? If you are, where are they located.

Comment: Almost all the Schengen countries along with Tunisia, Turkey, Qatar, Thailand, Singapore, Malaysia, UK etc

Answer (score 1):

> I would like to know if having a full-time job for some time qualifies
>   as the change in circumstances?

Yes. However it is just part of your whole profile which will be evaluated.

> In the US embassy website, they maintain that I shouldn't apply for
>   the visa again until my circumstances change significantly.

It is just a suggestion.

> Shall I wait for some more time (until I get the Permanent Residence
>   in Germany) and does the time-period between the applications play any
>   role?

That would be better, however it is not necessary. Additionally that does not guarantee you will get the visa. The time period plays a role only in that with a longer period of time, it is more likely that your circumstances have change and also that you do not appear desperate (successive rapid applications may smack of desperation, a red flag)

The fact that in your previous comment you indicate you obtained a UK visa a few months ago is a positive.

`Update: So I applied for the UK visa and received it within 15 days with no problems at all. For the previous visa refusal question, I described the case very briefly giving details about why I wanted to travel and how my circumstances changed.`